# Change GMT time format to 24 hours javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a GMT time format and I changed it to my local browser time by using:

```
var newDate = new Date(GMTFromat);
mytime= newDate.toLocaleString();
```

The output is:

```
3/12/2010 1:02:00 PM
```

Now I want to change 12 hours to 24 hours format in `javascript`.
Example:

```
3/12/2010 13:02:00
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556879/changing-the-1-24-hour-to-1-12-hour-for-the-gethours-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enter code here`Its a copy of [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664174/change-time-string-of-hhmm-am-pm-to-24-hour-time)

Code from the above link:

```
function to24Hour(str) {

  var tokens = /([10]?\d):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d) ([ap]m)/i.exec(str);

  if (tokens == null) { return null; }
    if (tokens[4].toLowerCase() === 'pm' && tokens[1] !== '12') {
      tokens[1] = '' + (12 + (+tokens[1]));
    } else if (tokens[4].toLowerCase() === 'am' && tokens[1] === '12') {
      tokens[1] = '00';
    }
  return tokens[1] + ':' + tokens[2] + ":" + tokens[3]; 
}
```

Edit:

```
var date = "3/12/2010 8:45:59 AM";
var dateTime = date.split(" ");
var datePart = dateTime[0];
var timePart = dateTime[1] + " " + dateTime[2];
timePart = to24Hour(timePart);

var finalDate = datePart + timePart;
```

Comment: thanks man! and if I want to keep the date too, what should I do? because it just returns the time. but I need both date and time together

Comment: you can separate the date part & time part from your input, then can pass the time part to this method , then append the result of this method with your date part

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in any number of ways, but I wanted to do it using just the `replace` method. Here you go:

```
(new Date()).toLocaleString().replace(/(.+ )(\d+)(:.+)(\wM)/g, function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, p4) {
    return p1 + (p4 === "PM" ? (12 + Number(p2)) : p2) + p3;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/5HJJr/2/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){
    alert(
        moment("3/12/2010 1:02:00 PM", "M/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A").
            format("M/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
    );
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RbD5R/5/)

Here small **hh** for 12-clock system and **HH** for 24 clock system.

Comment: check fiddle, it have link to it - momentjs date time lib